# Not able to open the excel files through browser - sharepoint 2010

Tags: office-web-apps

In my environment i am not able to open the excel files through browser. However i can able to access the powerpoint and word files through browser. Any solution for this issue ?

While opening the excel file it is prompting to : How would you like to open this file - Read only or Edit.